# Joining Two SQL statements with multiple conditions to run consecutively

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Row     Student   Major      
 1        Jenn    Math
 2        Jenn    Science
 3        Jenn    CS
 4        Mark    English
 5        Mark    History
 6        Steve   Math 
 7        Steve   Science
 8        Steve   Engineering
 9        Ann     Biology
 10       Ann     Chemistry
```

I am trying to look for patterns in consecutive rows where a student changed majors from Math to Science and then changed to a third major and flag those values so I would have:

```
 Row     Name    Major      Flagged_Values
 1        Jenn    Math
 2        Jenn    Science
 3        Jenn    CS                1
 4        Mark    English
 5        Mark    History
 6        Steve   Math 
 7        Steve   Science
 8        Steve   Engineering       1
 9        Ann     Biology
 10       Ann     Chemistry
```

In this case, students Jenn and Steve meet that critera, so they would get flagged with a 1.

I then flag those students who majored in Math, Science and Engineering consecutively  (which would be Steve in this case) and add another column with a 1 in it. My question is, if I have two separate statements to flag these patterns, and I later want to flag values where BOTH criterion are met, how would I do that? Would I use the `addBatch` method? I have code but it doesn't yield the desired results. I am using Java (JDBC) with an SQL library using an Oracle Database.

```
String x = "SELECT STUDENTS.ROW, STUDENTS.MAJOR, STUDENTS.NAME " +
  "CASE WHEN prior_row.NAME IS NOT NULL" +
  "AND EXISTS(SELECT 'x' FROM STUDENTS prior_row " +
  "WHERE STUDENTS.MAJOR = prior_row.MAJOR" +
  "AND STUDENTS.ROW > prior_row.ROW + 1" +
  "SELECT STUDENTS.MAJOR, STUDENTS.ROW, STUDENTS.NAME WHERE" +
  "MAJOR < (SELECT MAJOR FROM STUDENTS WHERE MAJOR = 'MATH' 
  "AND WHERE MAJOR > (SELECT MAJOR FROM STUDENTS WHERE MAJOR = 'SCIENCE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END Flagged_Values";

  st.addBatch(x);

String y = "SELECT STUDENTS.ROW, STUDENTS.MAJOR, STUDENTS.NAME" +
  "CASE WHEN previous.NAME IS NOT NULL" +
  "AND EXISTS(SELECT 'y' FROM STUDENTS previous" +
  "WHERE STUDENTS.MAJOR = previous.MAJOR" +
  "AND STUDENTS.ROW > previous.ROW + 1" +
  "SELECT STUDENTS.MAJOR, STUDENTS.ROW, STUDENTS.NAME WHERE" +
  "MAJOR < (SELECT THE_OUTCOME FROM STUDENTINFO WHERE MAJOR ='Math' +
  "AND WHERE MAJOR > (SELECT MAJOR FROM STUDENTS WHERE MAJOR = 'SCIENCE'" +
  "AND WHERE MAJOR > (SELECT MAJOR FROM STUDENTS WHERE MAJOR = 'Engineering'
  "THEN 1 ELSE NULL END Flag ";

  st.addBatch(y);
```

I am trying to compare for consecutive instances. My second question: Is this considered data mining?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `addBatch()` is only intended for DML (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) statements. Just run those two statements one after the other using `executeQuery()`

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: A_horse_with_no_name, Thanks, your answer helped!